# Access SQL Server 2019 Linux Database from frontend or API using Kubernetes service name

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, sql-server-2019

I have been using SQL Server 2017 Linux image for quite some time. I am able to deploy this to Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster with **Statefulset** and a service name exposed via a **Service** object. I can then connect to the SQL Server instance using the service name from web API or frontend application. The complete working example of this can be found in the repo
https://github.com/NileshGule/AKS-learning-series/tree/master/k8s/AKS

I upgraded to **SQL Server 2019 Linux** image using the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-kubernetes-manage?view=sqlallproducts-allversions. With the operator and the availability group deployment, I am able to create the database. However, I cannot access the database from the front end and Web API projects without giving in the loadbalancer IP address of the Availability Group primary service.

Is there any way to access the SQL Server 2019 using service discovery without specifying the IP address?

Comment: did you read the docs? you need to create a service to connect to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-kubernetes-connect?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

Comment: @4c74356b41 I have read the docs. Please note I am able to connect to SQL 2019 database using the IP of the ag primary service. In SQL 2017 we can use the name of the sql deployment to access the database using Kubernetes service discovery without knowing the IP of the server pod.
Refer to https://github.com/NileshGule/AKS-learning-series/blob/master/k8s/AKS/TechTalksAPI/api-deployment.yml
You can see that on line 48, I am referring to the sql 2017 instance using the db-deployment which is the Kubernetes service name